# coordinates not fitting at right place on ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to map coordinates of MIT using ggmap but geom_point() is not showing up at right location.

Here's what I did:

```
LAT <- 42.2 # coordinates of MIT
LON <- -71.1
mit_coor <- data.frame(LAT, LON)
qmap("boston", zoom = 11) + geom_point(aes(LON, LAT), color = "red", data = x)
```

Result is:

[image: mit using ggmap]

Clearly MIT is not showing up at right place. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When I search for `42.2, -71.1` on Google Maps, the pointer shows up at exactly the spot indicated in your map as well. Perhaps you want more precise coordinates for MIT? Something like `42.36, -71.09` might be closer?

Comment: I checked and found there is some issue in data provided. I'm taking a course "Analytic Edge" from MIT and there is a unit on housing price of Boston area which also has some coordinate data. 

There is some issue with that data, I was able to offset it and plot points where they should be.

Thanks